# Create indicator variables within a list

Tags: r, list, indicator

I have a `list` containing sequences of numbers.  I want to create a `list` that indicates all non-zero elements up to the first element that matches a defined limit.  I also want to create a `list` that indicates all non-zero elements after the first element to match the defined limit.

I prefer a base `R` solution.  Presumably the solution will use `lapply`, but I have not been able to come up with a simple solution.

Below is a minimally reproducible example in which the limit is 2:

```
my.limit <- 2
my.samples  <- list(0,c(1,2),0,c(0,1,1),0,0,0,0,0,c(1,1,2,2,3,4),c(0,1,2),0,c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3))
```

Here are the two desired `lists`:

```
within.limit  <- list(0,c(1,1),0,c(0,1,1),0,0,0,0,0,c(1,1,1,0,0,0),c(0,1,1),0,c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0))
outside.limit <- list(0,c(0,0),0,c(0,0,0),0,0,0,0,0,c(0,0,0,1,1,1),c(0,0,0),0,c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1))
```

Comment: Each sequences is sorted in increasing order?

Comment: Yes, each sequence is sorted in increasing order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` with `nomatch` argument as a very big number (should be greater than any length of the list, for some reason I couldn't use `Inf` here.)

```
within.limit1 <- lapply(my.samples, function(x) 
                 +(x > 0 & seq_along(x) <= match(my.limit, x, nomatch = 1000)))

outside.limit1 <- lapply(my.samples, function(x) 
                    +(seq_along(x) > match(my.limit, x, nomatch = 1000)))
```

Checking if output is correct to shown one :

```
all(mapply(function(x, y) all(x == y), within.limit, within.limit1))
#[1] TRUE
all(mapply(function(x, y) all(x == y), outside.limit, outside.limit1))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Very nice answer.  Could you explain the + sign?

Comment: The `+` sign converts logical values to integers. See the output of `+c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```r
within.limit <- lapply(my.samples, function(x) 
                           +(x!=0 & (x<limit | cumsum(x == limit)==1)))
outside.limit <- lapply(my.samples, function(x) 
                           +(x!=0 & (x>limit | cumsum(x == limit)>1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo <- function(samples, limit, within = TRUE) {
  `%cp%` <- if (within) `<=` else `>`
  lapply(samples, function(x) pmin(x, seq_along(x) %cp% match(my.limit, x, nomatch = 1e8)))
}

> all.equal(foo(my.samples, my.limit, FALSE), outside.limit)
# [1] TRUE
> all.equal(foo(my.samples, my.limit, TRUE), within.limit)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `findInterval`

```
lapply(my.samples, function(x) 
          +(x > 0 & seq_along(x) <= findInterval(my.limit, x)-1))
```

and

```
lapply(my.samples, function(x)  +(seq_along(x) > findInterval(my.limit, x)-1))
```